# VBA If-Then Object Required Error

Tags: vba, if-statement, runtime, runtime-error

I'm trying to change a complicated formula from + to =, based on the code I'm running.

At current, cells(5,3).formula is +(ABS(Q29)*G29), but I get the error Run-time Error '424': Object required when running this.  In the watches panel, Left(Cells(5,3).Formula,1) returns "+", and the code breaks on setting the "+" to "="

```
If Left(Cells(5, 3).Formula, 1) = "+" Then
Left(Cells(5, 3).Formula, 1) = "="
```

Edited: not a misspelling in the code

Comment: is it just misspelling with additional parenthesis inside this formula:`+ABS(Q29)*G29)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work, too:

```
Cells(5, 3).Formula = "=" & Cells(5, 3).Formula
```

which will keep `+` but formula is valid when starting with `=+`, too.

Comment: Wouldn't this leave the "+"?

Comment: indeed, will leave "+" but formula will be still valid when starting with "=+"

Answer (score 1):

I don't do much VBA for apps, but in VBScript Left(..) returns the left character, which doesn't make sense to assign something to it. You could try something like this:

```
Cells(5, 3).Formula = "=" & Right(Cells(5, 3).Formula, Len(Cells(5, 3).Formula) - 1)
```

This sets the Forumla to the current value of the Formula replacing the 1st character with an "=".

Comment: That's it, thanks so much! What exactly is the rationale behind your code?  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The Right function returns characters starting from the right hand side. Since we want to replace the first character, taking the length of the string - 1 characters gives us everything but the plus. We then tack the "=" to the front and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Mid` function to replace the "+" with a "=". It should look something like:

```
Cells(5, 3).Formula = "=" + Mid(Cells(5, 3).Formula, 2, Len(Cells(5, 3).Formula) - 1)
```

However, Mike J's answer using `Right` is easier to read and is probably more efficient.